# GCC compile error -- Compiler itself seems to error with truncating LOG file in RHEL 8 env

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have just setup a Linux box with RHEL 8 Server package and installed gcc along with developers tools.  My first program ICECast 2.4.4 is my first "configure" and "make" project on this system.  During the make process I am seeing what appears to be a GCC issue in a couple of errors in the class of truncating lines and buffer size.  The ICECast is being compile unadulterated right from the xiph.org site   I am not sure why this is the case, perhaps some here have seen this issue before?   Here is the snippet of the make STDOUT and STEDERR I collected with a redirect of these output to a file. I have three instances of the main.c like thee following:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -Wall -ffast-math -fsigned-char -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -g -O2 -MT cfgfile.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cfgfile.Tpo -c -o cfgfile.o cfgfile.c
mv -f .deps/cfgfile.Tpo .deps/cfgfile.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -Wall -ffast-math -fsigned-char -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
main.c:237:55: warning: â€˜%sâ€™ directive output may be truncated writing up to 4095 bytes into a region of size 986 [-Wformat-truncation=]
                 "FATAL: could not open error logging (%s): %s",
                                                       ^~
                 log_to_stderr?"standard error":fn_error,
                                                ~~~~~~~~
main.c:236:9: note: â€˜snprintfâ€™ output 41 or more bytes (assuming 4136) into a destination of size 1023
         snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 "FATAL: could not open error logging (%s): %s",
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
 main.c:236:9: note: â€˜snprintfâ€™ output 41 or more bytes (assuming 4136) into a destination of size 1023
         snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 "FATAL: could not open error logging (%s): %s",
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 log_to_stderr?"standard error":fn_error,
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 strerror(errno));
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:259:56: warning: â€˜%sâ€™ directive output may be truncated writing up to 4095 bytes into a region of size 985 [-Wformat-truncation=]
                 "FATAL: could not open access logging (%s): %s",
                                                        ^~
main.c:258:9: note: â€˜snprintfâ€™ output 42 or more bytes (assuming 4137) into a destination of size 1023
         snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 "FATAL: could not open access logging (%s): %s",
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 log_to_stderr?"standard error":fn_access,
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 strerror(errno));
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:271:58: warning: â€˜%sâ€™ directive output may be truncated writing up to 4095 bytes into a region of size 983 [-Wformat-truncation=]
                 "FATAL: could not open playlist logging (%s): %s",
                                                          ^~
main.c:270:13: note: â€˜snprintfâ€™ output 44 or more bytes (assuming 4139) into a destination of size 1023
             snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)-1,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 "FATAL: could not open playlist logging (%s): %s",
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 log_to_stderr?"standard error":fn_playlist,
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 strerror(errno));
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -Wall -ffast-math -fsigned-char -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -g -O2 -MT logging.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/logging.Tpo -c -o logging.o logging.c
mv -f .deps/logging.Tpo .deps/logging.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -Wall -ffast-math -fsigned-char -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -g -O2 -MT sighandler.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sighandler.Tpo -c -o sighandler.o sighandler.c
mv -f .deps/sighandler.Tpo .deps/sighandler.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -Wall -ffast-math -fsigned-char -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread -g -O2 -MT connection.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/connection.Tpo -c -o connection.o connection.c
mv -f .deps/connection.Tpo .deps/connection.Po
g
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the code that the compiler is complaining about. It seems like it is tryiing to tell you that the buffer you're trying to print in to is not big enough.

Comment: Those are warnings about your code, not compiler errors. (And really annoying ones; I usually turn that warning off.)

Comment: Thank you both for this clarification.   It did turn out to be the warning on the buffer size print to STDOut/STDErr and not a truncation of binary code into the executable being generated.    We tested the IceCast and it is working after reviewingt both of your responses against the gcc compile log/status output.